# Android Device Monitor don't show any thing it's empty

Tags: android

as i cleared in the address, Android Device Monitor don't show any thing it's empty
it was working good but i tried to explore something but no thing is appeared

Comment: Yeah, it does that from time to time. Usually unplugging the device/restarting the emulator/restarting android studio fixes the problem. If that doesn't fix it, it'll come back at some point on its own.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the device is locked or the application is in dead state in the android studio. If you re-select the app you like to test, it generally works out for the best.